# Xamarin questions about Controls and Storyboard

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm a newbie in Xamarin development and I'm still stuck at the beginning (Xamarin.iOS)...

1) I tried to create a splashscreen, it worked but I faced an issue. I put a label controls in my Splashscreen and I set the width to the following option : Fill parent (in the layout tab). But, everytime I run the application in debugging mode, the width come back to the initial width...

2) My Splashscreen never dispose, even though I create a Main storyboard that should be loaded right after the Splashscreen...I can't figure out what the problem is.

if you have any idea, tutorial or something, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) splash screen : You should create LaunchScreen storyboard and define name of that in Info.plist under Launch Images .   for layout of your table, you should first learn basics of auto layout. Here is link to tutorial:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/designer_auto_layout/

2) define your storyboard name in Main Interface under Info.Plist 
That will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks @iOS_devloper